# Converting numpy ndarray into pandas dataframe with column names and types

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Edit: As explained below in @floydian's comment, the problem was that calling `a = np.array(a, dtype=d)` creates an a double array which was causing the problem.

I am aware that this has been already asked multiple times, and in fact am looking at [Creating a Pandas DataFrame with a numpy array containing multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647054/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-numpy-array-containing-multiple-types/21647198#21647198) answer right now. But I still seem to have a problem while converting. It must be something very simple that I am missing. I hope that someone can be so kind and point it out. Sample code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
d = [('x','float'), ('y','int')]
a = np.array(a, dtype=d)

# Try 1
df= pd.DataFrame(a)
# Result - ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

# Try 2
i = [1,2]
df= pd.DataFrame(a, index=i)
# Result - Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: DataFrame with specified column names and data types

Comment: I mean, yeah, but what does it look like? Is the first column int and the second float?

Comment: For example, are you looking for `pd.DataFrame(a.ravel())`?

Comment: oh right, yes that's the idea: the first column int and the second float

Answer (score 2):

I would define the array like this:

```
a = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=[('x','float'), ('y', 'int')])
pd.DataFrame(a)
```

gets what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately in my original problem the array is defined in the way I did it above.

Comment: `a = np.array(a, dtype=d)` creates two 2x2 arrays, `a['x']` with float as dtype applied to all values and `a['y']` with int as dtype applied to all values. I am guessing this is the reason why you're getting all those errors.

Comment: That was indeed the reason. Thank you for pointing me out in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

One option to separate it after the fact could be e.g.

```
pd.DataFrame(a.astype("float32").T, columns=a.dtype.names).astype({k: v[0] for k, v in a.dtype.fields.items()})

Out[296]: 
     x  y
0  1.0  3
1  2.0  4
```