# plotting line and scatter plot in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I am currently doing a course i Machine Learning from Coursera ( https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-foundations/lecture/6wD6H/visualizing-predictions-of-simple-model-with-matplotlib ). The course use Graphlab Create framework for during the course for learning and assignments. I don't want to use `Graphlab`, instead I am using `pandas`, `numpy` for assignments.

In the course, the instructor has created a regression model, and then he shows the prediction using `matplotlib`:

#### Build Regression Model

```
sqft_model = graphlab.linear_regression.create(train_data, target='price', features=['sqft_living'],validation_set=None)
```

and then the prediction code is as follows:

```
plt.plot(test_data['sqft_living'],test_data['price'],'.',
        test_data['sqft_living'],sqft_model.predict(test_data),'-')
```

The result is:

[image: prediction image]

In the above image, blue dots are test data, green line is the prediction from the simple regression.
I am a complete beginner to programming and python. I wanted to use free resources such as pandas and `scikit`. I have used following to do the same in `Ipython`:

#### Build Regression Model

```
from pandas.stats.api import ols
sqft_model = ols(y=train_data['price'], x=train_data['sqft_living'])
```

But, I get the following error while inputting the prediction code:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Thus, I am not able to produce the desired result as done by the instructor (i.e. the image shown above). Can anyone help me out?

pls find the below link to download data:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EDAAD532F68FDF49!1091&authkey=!AKs341lbRnuCt9w&ithint=folder%2cipynb

Comment: Hi @Drjnker...  I get the following error while inputting the prediction code:  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: May the problem come from your `train_data` ?

Comment: Thanks @Drjnker..I will check> Meanwhile, could you pls let me know what is the meaning of : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous...?

Comment: You must be looking for a condition on a serie but python doesn't know if you want "the series isn't empty", "an element of the serie is true", or "all elements of the serie are true".. that's why it gives you `a.empty`, `a.all()` ... Although it doesnt make much sense in your code (from where I sit)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue here is that the Pandas OLS model can't understand GraphLab's SArray. Try converting the SFrames `train_data` and `test_data` into a Pandas Dataframe first - the following works for me:

```
df_train = train_data.to_dataframe()
model = old(y=df_train['price'], x=df_train['sqft_living'])
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help... when I input the above command, i m getting:    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_dataframe'.. AM I missing something... ..Thanks !

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763012/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-array-how-do-i-specify-the-index-colum) but I don't know what type is your data.

Comment: @Drjnker..I have provided Onedrive link  ( Edited above) to download data and code files i am using,.. could you pls check..