# How to write a numpy ndarray to a textfile?

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, numpy-ndarray

Say that I got this *ndarray* using *numpy* that I want to write to a text file. :

```
[[1   2   3   4]
[5   6   7   8]
[9   10   11   12]]
```

**This is my code:**

```
width, height = matrix.shape
with open('file.txt', 'w') as foo:
    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            foo.write(str(matrix[x, y]))
foo.close()
```

The problem is that I get all the lines of the *ndarray* in just one line, however I want it to be written to the file as this :

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply iterate over each row:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    for row in ndarray:
        f.write(str(row))
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, with some modifications, your answer was the one I am looking for.
I'll consider this as the correct answer.

Comment: @singrium Glad to help. What were the modifications you made? Can I include them in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve the shape as described, I would use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763012/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-array-how-do-i-specify-the-index-colum) describes how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

your_data = np.array([np.arange(5), np.arange(5), np.arange(5)])

# can pass your own column names if needed
your_df = pd.DataFrame(your_data) 

your_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, your solution works perfectly, but I didn't want to use pandas.