# Convert a numpy array to a DataFrame in pyspark to export as csv

Tags: arrays, numpy, dataframe, pyspark

I have a numpy array in pyspark and I would like to convert this to a DataFrame so I can write it out as a csv to view it.

I read the data in initially from a DataFrame however I had to convert to an array in order to use `numpy.random.normal()`. Now I want to convert the data back so I can write it out as a csv to view it.

I have tried the following directly on the array

```
zarr.write.csv("/mylocation/inHDFS")
```

however I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I needed to convert the numpy array to an rdd as follows;

```
zrdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([zarr])
```

Then convert this to a DataFrame using the following (where we also now define the column header);

```
df = zrdd.map(lambda x: x.tolist()).toDF(["SOR"])
```

This I could then write out as per normal like such;

```
df.write.csv("/hdfs/mylocation")
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy array and Spark Dataframe are totally different structures. The first one is local and doesn't have column names, the second is distributed (or distribute-ready in local mode) and has columns with strong typing.

I'd recommend to convert the numpy array to Pandas DF first as described here: [Creating a Pandas DataFrame from a Numpy array: How do I specify the index column and column headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763012/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-array-how-do-i-specify-the-index-colum), and then convert it to spark one using:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
df.write.csv('/hdfs/path')
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is however that I don't have pandas as I am using pyspark