# How can I convert an array of class objects to a dataframe with columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

With the following class:

```
class Test:
    a : str
    b : str
```

and the following data frame:

```
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b']
```

how can I convert an array, or list, of class Test into a pandas dataframe with matching columns?

---

Edit:

Let me add a more concrete example:

```
class Test:
    a: int
    b: int

    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

l = [Test(10, 20), Test(50, 60)]

output = pd.DataFrame(l,
                  columns=['a', 'b'],
                  index=range(len(l)))
```

and the error I get is:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 2)

Comment: Are you having trouble with the typical way to create a DataFrame? For instance, `output = pd.DataFrame([test.a, test.b], columns=['a', 'b'])`, where `test = Test()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Pandas DataFrame from a Numpy array: How do I specify the index column and column headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763012/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-array-how-do-i-specify-the-index-colum)

Comment: @PyNoob: I put a concrete example with the error

Comment: @tim: the questions may be related, but they're not exactly the same since the other question involves part of the list to become the header, which is not the case here

Comment: I'm not sure what you intended to do, but `Test(10, 20)` evaluates to `<__main__.Test at 0x1db821405c0>`  - one element; so `pd.DataFrame(l)` tells panda to expect one column and two rows, while `columns=['a', 'b']` implies two columns. Hence the error.

Comment: You should usually try to show an expected output as well.

Comment: @Akaisteph7: yes, I am not used to formulate Pandas questions, but I'm slowly realizing they require quite a lot more detail than in other fields :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `vars` to convert all the attributes of the class into a dict:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

tests = [Test(10, 20), Test(50, 60)]
df = pd.DataFrame([vars(t) for t in tests])
```

Comment: this is working, thanks! can you explain me the [vars(t)..] section and why it works? kind of new to python, but very new to pandas (like 4 days :))

Comment: to clarify, I understand vars(t), but I don't understand the vars(t) for ...; I would understand for t in tests: somelist.append(vars(t))

Comment: It's called list comprehension. Basically a one-liner loop. `[vars(t) for t in tests]` apply the function `vars` on every element in `tests`. Since `vars(t)` returns a dictionary, `[vars(t) for ...]` return a list of dictionaries

Comment: I didn’t know about list comprehension; I’m reading about it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this is to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([test.__dict__ for test in tests])
```