# Split: Convert NumPy format into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have NumPy format of split function, what is want to do is convert this format into pandas format. 
the idea is to split each object separately

```
input_num = 10
train = np.array([np.float32(x) for x in line.split(",")[0:input_num]])
test  = np.array([np.float32(x) for x in line.split(",")[input_num:]])
```

Comment: You can do `pd.Series(test)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763012/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-array-how-do-i-specify-the-index-colum

Comment: What do `train` and `test` look like?  `shape`? `dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj `dtype` is float `train` 80% and `test` 20%

Comment: @DanielMesejo How can use `pd.Series(test)` ? where to add it in code ?

Comment: `pd_test = pd.Series(test)` after your second line

Comment: @DanielMesejo I am facing this error .....  

File "<ipython-input-14-e631db589bc2>", line 2
    train = np.array([np.float32(x) for x in line.split(",")[0:input_num]])
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: `80%` is not a `shape`.

Comment: @hpaulj the `shape ` is 40300