# Is there a way to convert npz files to panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large npz file that l've loaded with numpy's np.load. I want to convert this to panda's dataframe so l can apply machine learning algorithms (KNN, K-Means, DT) using scikit-learn. I am new to python so my experience is very limited to this library. Thank you for the help.

This is what l have so far:

```
dataset = np.load('./example.npz')

test_data = dataset['data']

test_labels = dataset['labels']
```

`print data.shape` gives `(17000, 78400)`

`print labels.shape` gives `(17000, 1)`

Comment: Try to refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308247/8185479

Comment: I'm pretty sure that scikit-learn will work with `numpy.ndarray` objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to structure your dataframe, but this will load the npz file with the labels as index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

npz = np.load('/path/to/npz.npz')
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({item: npz[item] for item in npz.files}, orient='index')
```

if you want to load the arrays into a single column use:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({item: [npz[item]] for item in npz.files}, orient='index')
```

Just drop the `orient='index'` if you want to load the labels as columns.

Answer (score -7):

Please try out this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
```