# python converting list to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a variable `y` as below. It is a list with 2 elements. When i convert it to a dataframe `xyz` it seems that i get 2 rows but just one column. I would like to have 2 rows with multiple columns. each columns should have only one value in it and columns names should be 0,1,2,3, etc

How could i do the same?

```
print(len(y))
print(type(y))
2
<class 'list'>

xyz=pd.DataFrame.from_records(y)
type (xyz)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
xyz

0
0   [-0.9459755, -0.47805053, -0.65050876, 0.77347...
1   [-0.9459755, -0.47805053, -0.65050876, 0.77347...
```

y as below

```
[array([[-0.9459755 , -0.47805053, -0.65050876,  0.7734777 ,  0.552691  ,
        -0.19007854,  0.9223234 ,  0.27941042, -0.7322695 , -0.99998975,
        -0.37605256,  0.8916531 ,  0.983763  ,  0.2527561 ,  0.966363  ,
        -0.7447939 , -0.5058228 , -0.6355803 ,  0.420939  , -0.7473378 ,
         0.74549365,  0.9999191 ,  0.36683556,  0.31255466,  0.4609189 ,
         0.9825759 , -0.8520847 ,  0.9575349 ,  0.9682904 ,  0.72985345,
        -0.82898533,  0.14331765, -0.98895043, -0.23441169, -0.7558871 ,
        -0.9913596 ,  0.39418277, -0.84416234,  0.05476778, -0.01005056,
        -0.94226193,  0.24747927,  0.99995273, -0.13606967,  0.13124019,
        -0.34404624, -0.99999994,  0.16850327, -0.8896826 ,  0.75479925,
         0.6656554 ,  0.5275847 ,  0.27075547,  0.49543703,  0.43383783,
         0.05168212, -0.11341204,  0.10182644, -0.22263326, -0.63695884,
        -0.62449884,  0.2913445 , -0.84347934, -0.9449906 ,  0.82978284,
         0.6233054 , -0.076456  , -0.2860726 , -0.12531959, -0.0440293 ,
         0.92798275,  0.27617946,  0.27131325, -0.90081406,  0.37721077,
         0.31383792, -0.6580769 ,  1.        , -0.44372475, -0.9799322 ,
         0.73667705,  0.5613586 ,  0.5506944 , -0.01951157,  0.298312  ,
        -1.        ,  0.40395644, -0.12005024, -0.99280196,  0.25549296,
         0.58356893, -0.28049406,  0.342898  ,  0.61289656, -0.4513767 ,
        -0.34312075, -0.29862905, -0.7756922 , -0.23678726, -0.25012112,
        -0.01759785, -0.28374395, -0.2618543 , -0.35386655,  0.28066075,
        -0.482542  , -0.54826105,  0.44234577, -0.02860786,  0.7147769 ,
         0.45068547, -0.38843894,  0.5060407 , -0.97053695,  0.67816174,
        -0.2818997 , -0.98881775, -0.6243588 , -0.992165  ,  0.71923774,
        -0.279121  , -0.25058544,  0.9760995 ,  0.01690155,  0.39211938,
         0.01538094, -0.6557028 , -1.        , -0.5813251 , -0.41143104,
        -0.09620688, -0.20363976, -0.9794194 , -0.9636516 ,  0.6528108 ,
         0.97018564,  0.16890207,  0.99986917, -0.28804392,  0.9545565 ,
        -0.25736585, -0.5225193 ,  0.47669268, -0.45857254,  0.6629523 ,
         0.33144143, -0.7786891 ,  0.2574491 , -0.05056868,  0.06687481,
        -0.572528  , -0.20754746, -0.58802915, -0.97018045, -0.40681118,
         0.970967  , -0.37611288, -0.8045078 ,  0.18828286, -0.16196367,
        -0.4732573 ,  0.88972455,  0.5881976 ,  0.37267888, -0.19704172,
         0.39486232,  0.13269943,  0.54943895, -0.8223527 ,  0.1638822 ,
         0.45692173, -0.3252729 , -0.59520465, -0.985078  , -0.41795856,
         0.64682806,  0.99037033,  0.8276212 ,  0.29061356,  0.58312225,
        -0.16352373,  0.64946914, -0.9703819 ,  0.9829681 , -0.35020226,
         0.26412863, -0.16023819,  0.48377427, -0.9017009 , -0.04951501,
         0.88109   , -0.572556  , -0.88953966,  0.03719393, -0.51457113,
        -0.43427563, -0.66786784,  0.55420285, -0.30180818, -0.35544968,
        -0.05752672,  0.94897026,  0.9884329 ,  0.8514675 , -0.02706478,
         0.6300914 , -0.94219875, -0.6096796 ,  0.08986723,  0.20492023,
         0.2656025 ,  0.99588263, -0.4211055 , -0.1923249 , -0.95686954,
        -0.99127907, -0.08337305, -0.9306704 , -0.18833733, -0.7482102 ,
         0.55400956,  0.0555265 ,  0.46837628,  0.38679695, -0.99511546,
        -0.80549157,  0.4122052 , -0.37963787,  0.4697992 , -0.16269048,
         0.5950353 ,  0.88734823, -0.5756747 ,  0.83287156,  0.9290157 ,
        -0.7439878 , -0.828965  ,  0.8942273 , -0.313458  ,  0.92042863,
        -0.6451802 ,  0.99454874,  0.83056575,  0.8252365 , -0.9574431 ,
        -0.5787046 , -0.93613344, -0.58610857, -0.10107749, -0.17892347,
         0.81836295,  0.6172731 ,  0.41681796,  0.57118464, -0.6225571 ,
         0.9989582 , -0.7001649 , -0.96139723, -0.27740443, -0.23548205,
        -0.98848706,  0.74846864,  0.35963902, -0.10826006, -0.46944666,
        -0.6967058 , -0.97237617,  0.9392128 ,  0.10147385,  0.9926904 ,
        -0.16881682, -0.946524  , -0.5884638 , -0.9540271 , -0.24724305,
        -0.28957403, -0.15261933, -0.11785159, -0.9682255 ,  0.49430174,
         0.5003349 ,  0.48061895, -0.6137284 ,  0.999326  ,  0.9999998 ,
         0.976841  ,  0.91392696,  0.9618617 , -0.9992805 , -0.67680204,
         0.9999956 , -0.98577553, -1.        , -0.9550538 , -0.70691264,
         0.465085  , -1.        , -0.15956445,  0.03087116, -0.9547435 ,
         0.37775376,  0.9846359 ,  0.99576795, -1.        ,  0.89814603,
         0.9636626 , -0.6454543 ,  0.9496282 , -0.26886773,  0.9733797 ,
         0.6540432 ,  0.2397651 , -0.29637057,  0.43193617, -0.84643066,
        -0.91404974, -0.29513764, -0.59079194,  0.9944733 ,  0.16350774,
        -0.7428708 , -0.9541641 ,  0.15665837, -0.253073  , -0.18864983,
        -0.97502136, -0.14366363,  0.32544258,  0.80569303,  0.14729789,
         0.28502184, -0.7632915 ,  0.27309316, -0.21719639,  0.47755685,
         0.6861862 , -0.95450646, -0.7322332 , -0.31859246, -0.3092003 ,
        -0.45525196, -0.96703494,  0.97626525, -0.47885466,  0.6296605 ,
         1.        ,  0.19711891, -0.92267424,  0.55910766,  0.26710632,
        -0.35919994,  1.        ,  0.7761388 , -0.9830818 , -0.5782019 ,
         0.40678364, -0.55976874, -0.5471115 ,  0.99937713, -0.33048865,
        -0.5061277 , -0.14908014,  0.9785268 , -0.99043804,  0.9828222 ,
        -0.9187875 , -0.9773213 ,  0.9800687 ,  0.955108  , -0.63989365,
        -0.78066677,  0.25093687, -0.52095413,  0.35847044, -0.9796438 ,
         0.77040577,  0.5041405 , -0.11713739,  0.90462315, -0.90723217,
        -0.5658021 ,  0.3393464 , -0.57253885, -0.03464808,  0.7852318 ,
         0.5863543 , -0.2903683 ,  0.10524008, -0.3157491 , -0.3283432 ,
        -0.98630184,  0.25248316,  1.        , -0.2932054 ,  0.43194744,
        -0.39159498, -0.02471775, -0.12938915,  0.5425912 ,  0.63316727,
        -0.31224072, -0.90678704,  0.6802484 , -0.98032105, -0.98643327,
         0.88515776,  0.2762025 , -0.25967157,  0.9999937 ,  0.52587867,
         0.18437354,  0.34015328,  0.97531146, -0.00961124,  0.6977997 ,
         0.7714908 ,  0.97960067, -0.19878545,  0.5547651 ,  0.91813415,
        -0.76973844, -0.29839078, -0.6457684 ,  0.11847758, -0.93472254,
         0.04859285, -0.9728577 ,  0.9758918 ,  0.79083323,  0.37397337,
         0.29322428,  0.3463571 ,  1.        , -0.28344712,  0.74565566,
        -0.65729904,  0.89706427, -0.9992633 , -0.85835195, -0.42205122,
         0.02660483, -0.6537962 , -0.31771183,  0.3093419 , -0.97574544,
         0.5961652 ,  0.48927927, -0.99429876, -0.99184316, -0.10422545,
         0.85884523,  0.00486639, -0.9560245 , -0.71263295, -0.59398985,
         0.5138035 , -0.27638632, -0.96817255,  0.17129657, -0.295536  ,
         0.56728745, -0.26840574,  0.5732834 ,  0.6681473 ,  0.7473094 ,
        -0.42653623, -0.05367717, -0.02169049, -0.8601829 ,  0.8354379 ,
        -0.84583515, -0.73801994, -0.1758596 ,  1.        , -0.5074421 ,
         0.74395454,  0.8140395 ,  0.8012395 , -0.19783951,  0.12990536,
         0.8705507 ,  0.23519993, -0.60337013, -0.6908616 , -0.85193384,
        -0.41151592,  0.6187978 ,  0.25217745,  0.43870094,  0.85306245,
         0.75531286,  0.20293558, -0.01406304, -0.10706785,  0.9998205 ,
        -0.14611307, -0.24235162, -0.6237957 ,  0.02892364, -0.4086271 ,
        -0.5665821 ,  1.        ,  0.342323  ,  0.328192  , -0.99026304,
        -0.63736963, -0.9433317 ,  0.9999989 ,  0.9019552 , -0.87858593,
         0.6951615 ,  0.5400228 , -0.09183987,  0.8488278 , -0.18790367,
        -0.31657013,  0.317574  ,  0.13583037,  0.96701694, -0.622579  ,
        -0.97985405, -0.6803688 ,  0.42359763, -0.9725251 ,  0.9994953 ,
        -0.542078  , -0.24575908, -0.4273482 , -0.01201347,  0.7613651 ,
         0.00731448, -0.98946   , -0.11817224,  0.2206094 ,  0.97735566,
         0.1929144 , -0.591835  , -0.9492599 ,  0.50090253,  0.62826014,
        -0.76978254, -0.9621842 ,  0.9751784 , -0.9908679 ,  0.66289395,
         1.        ,  0.31703115, -0.43707806,  0.15467693, -0.56510115,
         0.36916867, -0.28950256,  0.7145889 , -0.9760138 , -0.48779896,
        -0.13801542,  0.38100198, -0.13986678,  0.13865034,  0.784588  ,
         0.20181029, -0.49005198, -0.6200816 , -0.02545768,  0.51952076,
         0.8692346 , -0.36663455, -0.19382007, -0.01067433, -0.19743322,
        -0.95507383, -0.24380404, -0.29982236, -0.9999688 ,  0.79986584,
        -1.        ,  0.2695148 , -0.08518916, -0.18281214,  0.8777597 ,
         0.5447604 ,  0.49969584, -0.8048793 , -0.694106  ,  0.61722565,
         0.81101197, -0.29681554, -0.13316315, -0.7884097 ,  0.25134793,
        -0.07460118,  0.40256706, -0.33344275,  0.8121781 , -0.24125008,
         1.        ,  0.19404748, -0.61283517, -0.9879942 ,  0.22347625,
        -0.18747559,  0.99999994, -0.9469065 , -0.9642234 ,  0.35057634,
        -0.70234084, -0.88181317,  0.2818043 , -0.00923758, -0.8131019 ,
        -0.90696543,  0.97128403,  0.9361259 , -0.61874884,  0.5001946 ,
        -0.3375339 , -0.616567  ,  0.01690421,  0.60233366,  0.99087167,
         0.48337436,  0.9235803 , -0.08378224, -0.24273983,  0.9741196 ,
         0.13318112,  0.6367294 ,  0.20994084,  1.        ,  0.2779764 ,
        -0.94073814,  0.23566417, -0.9866463 , -0.20943974, -0.97578436,
         0.27121937,  0.18821484,  0.9488337 , -0.3315034 ,  0.96209157,
        -0.5729339 ,  0.05573122, -0.5332821 , -0.03750358,  0.37780896,
        -0.9583214 , -0.9877656 , -0.9878868 ,  0.6314601 , -0.4537851 ,
        -0.0323552 ,  0.24128953,  0.11342575,  0.46291897,  0.5541575 ,
        -1.        ,  0.95559114,  0.42294934,  0.77785254,  0.9710445 ,
         0.7026142 ,  0.42804685,  0.33771977, -0.9899562 , -0.9919649 ,
        -0.40367672, -0.2135195 ,  0.7956065 ,  0.6891527 ,  0.9223903 ,
         0.4893354 , -0.51037455, -0.35977358, -0.28881362, -0.7840159 ,
        -0.99540436,  0.47370532, -0.3997906 , -0.98349714,  0.95919394,
        -0.13264774, -0.16179705,  0.13471113, -0.69341195,  0.97857916,
         0.8883015 ,  0.5587162 ,  0.13504937,  0.5614963 ,  0.9285318 ,
         0.97044104,  0.9836765 , -0.6593045 ,  0.8397449 , -0.38409153,
         0.56074977,  0.6409418 , -0.9576191 ,  0.15008189,  0.32664824,
        -0.24418157,  0.22771904, -0.26481634, -0.9884511 ,  0.34720448,
        -0.17766179,  0.64612764, -0.38605484, -0.0186708 , -0.48134714,
        -0.10996526, -0.7571417 , -0.76564854,  0.6945152 ,  0.3526681 ,
         0.9315834 ,  0.71839595, -0.12440112, -0.6379952 , -0.2399207 ,
        -0.5485674 , -0.94808227,  0.9552906 , -0.03638262, -0.05993683,
         0.3750182 , -0.04180279,  0.7299626 , -0.08958837, -0.39086553,
        -0.39726564, -0.7406826 ,  0.90645045, -0.09038296, -0.56262934,
        -0.7078029 ,  0.75853217,  0.25826415,  0.99992806, -0.564312  ,
        -0.8097277 , -0.23506235, -0.442809  ,  0.354424  , -0.39383766,
        -1.        ,  0.37609363, -0.36428654,  0.53091085, -0.62894225,
         0.57903147, -0.50878316, -0.9908445 , -0.19053973,  0.4337847 ,
         0.610516  , -0.59371257, -0.66226494,  0.5636608 ,  0.06387527,
         0.95153147,  0.8910796 ,  0.10300018,  0.35302562,  0.6912232 ,
        -0.4406702 , -0.6655127 ,  0.951942  ]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.9459755 , -0.47805053, -0.65050876,  0.7734777 ,  0.552691  ,
        -0.19007854,  0.9223234 ,  0.27941042, -0.7322695 , -0.99998975,
        -0.37605256,  0.8916531 ,  0.983763  ,  0.2527561 ,  0.966363  ,
        -0.7447939 , -0.5058228 , -0.6355803 ,  0.420939  , -0.7473378 ,
         0.74549365,  0.9999191 ,  0.36683556,  0.31255466,  0.4609189 ,
         0.9825759 , -0.8520847 ,  0.9575349 ,  0.9682904 ,  0.72985345,
        -0.82898533,  0.14331765, -0.98895043, -0.23441169, -0.7558871 ,
        -0.9913596 ,  0.39418277, -0.84416234,  0.05476778, -0.01005056,
        -0.94226193,  0.24747927,  0.99995273, -0.13606967,  0.13124019,
        -0.34404624, -0.99999994,  0.16850327, -0.8896826 ,  0.75479925,
         0.6656554 ,  0.5275847 ,  0.27075547,  0.49543703,  0.43383783,
         0.05168212, -0.11341204,  0.10182644, -0.22263326, -0.63695884,
        -0.62449884,  0.2913445 , -0.84347934, -0.9449906 ,  0.82978284,
         0.6233054 , -0.076456  , -0.2860726 , -0.12531959, -0.0440293 ,
         0.92798275,  0.27617946,  0.27131325, -0.90081406,  0.37721077,
         0.31383792, -0.6580769 ,  1.        , -0.44372475, -0.9799322 ,
         0.73667705,  0.5613586 ,  0.5506944 , -0.01951157,  0.298312  ,
        -1.        ,  0.40395644, -0.12005024, -0.99280196,  0.25549296,
         0.58356893, -0.28049406,  0.342898  ,  0.61289656, -0.4513767 ,
        -0.34312075, -0.29862905, -0.7756922 , -0.23678726, -0.25012112,
        -0.01759785, -0.28374395, -0.2618543 , -0.35386655,  0.28066075,
        -0.482542  , -0.54826105,  0.44234577, -0.02860786,  0.7147769 ,
         0.45068547, -0.38843894,  0.5060407 , -0.97053695,  0.67816174,
        -0.2818997 , -0.98881775, -0.6243588 , -0.992165  ,  0.71923774,
        -0.279121  , -0.25058544,  0.9760995 ,  0.01690155,  0.39211938,
         0.01538094, -0.6557028 , -1.        , -0.5813251 , -0.41143104,
        -0.09620688, -0.20363976, -0.9794194 , -0.9636516 ,  0.6528108 ,
         0.97018564,  0.16890207,  0.99986917, -0.28804392,  0.9545565 ,
        -0.25736585, -0.5225193 ,  0.47669268, -0.45857254,  0.6629523 ,
         0.33144143, -0.7786891 ,  0.2574491 , -0.05056868,  0.06687481,
        -0.572528  , -0.20754746, -0.58802915, -0.97018045, -0.40681118,
         0.970967  , -0.37611288, -0.8045078 ,  0.18828286, -0.16196367,
        -0.4732573 ,  0.88972455,  0.5881976 ,  0.37267888, -0.19704172,
         0.39486232,  0.13269943,  0.54943895, -0.8223527 ,  0.1638822 ,
         0.45692173, -0.3252729 , -0.59520465, -0.985078  , -0.41795856,
         0.64682806,  0.99037033,  0.8276212 ,  0.29061356,  0.58312225,
        -0.16352373,  0.64946914, -0.9703819 ,  0.9829681 , -0.35020226,
         0.26412863, -0.16023819,  0.48377427, -0.9017009 , -0.04951501,
         0.88109   , -0.572556  , -0.88953966,  0.03719393, -0.51457113,
        -0.43427563, -0.66786784,  0.55420285, -0.30180818, -0.35544968,
        -0.05752672,  0.94897026,  0.9884329 ,  0.8514675 , -0.02706478,
         0.6300914 , -0.94219875, -0.6096796 ,  0.08986723,  0.20492023,
         0.2656025 ,  0.99588263, -0.4211055 , -0.1923249 , -0.95686954,
        -0.99127907, -0.08337305, -0.9306704 , -0.18833733, -0.7482102 ,
         0.55400956,  0.0555265 ,  0.46837628,  0.38679695, -0.99511546,
        -0.80549157,  0.4122052 , -0.37963787,  0.4697992 , -0.16269048,
         0.5950353 ,  0.88734823, -0.5756747 ,  0.83287156,  0.9290157 ,
        -0.7439878 , -0.828965  ,  0.8942273 , -0.313458  ,  0.92042863,
        -0.6451802 ,  0.99454874,  0.83056575,  0.8252365 , -0.9574431 ,
        -0.5787046 , -0.93613344, -0.58610857, -0.10107749, -0.17892347,
         0.81836295,  0.6172731 ,  0.41681796,  0.57118464, -0.6225571 ,
         0.9989582 , -0.7001649 , -0.96139723, -0.27740443, -0.23548205,
        -0.98848706,  0.74846864,  0.35963902, -0.10826006, -0.46944666,
        -0.6967058 , -0.97237617,  0.9392128 ,  0.10147385,  0.9926904 ,
        -0.16881682, -0.946524  , -0.5884638 , -0.9540271 , -0.24724305,
        -0.28957403, -0.15261933, -0.11785159, -0.9682255 ,  0.49430174,
         0.5003349 ,  0.48061895, -0.6137284 ,  0.999326  ,  0.9999998 ,
         0.976841  ,  0.91392696,  0.9618617 , -0.9992805 , -0.67680204,
         0.9999956 , -0.98577553, -1.        , -0.9550538 , -0.70691264,
         0.465085  , -1.        , -0.15956445,  0.03087116, -0.9547435 ,
         0.37775376,  0.9846359 ,  0.99576795, -1.        ,  0.89814603,
         0.9636626 , -0.6454543 ,  0.9496282 , -0.26886773,  0.9733797 ,
         0.6540432 ,  0.2397651 , -0.29637057,  0.43193617, -0.84643066,
        -0.91404974, -0.29513764, -0.59079194,  0.9944733 ,  0.16350774,
        -0.7428708 , -0.9541641 ,  0.15665837, -0.253073  , -0.18864983,
        -0.97502136, -0.14366363,  0.32544258,  0.80569303,  0.14729789,
         0.28502184, -0.7632915 ,  0.27309316, -0.21719639,  0.47755685,
         0.6861862 , -0.95450646, -0.7322332 , -0.31859246, -0.3092003 ,
        -0.45525196, -0.96703494,  0.97626525, -0.47885466,  0.6296605 ,
         1.        ,  0.19711891, -0.92267424,  0.55910766,  0.26710632,
        -0.35919994,  1.        ,  0.7761388 , -0.9830818 , -0.5782019 ,
         0.40678364, -0.55976874, -0.5471115 ,  0.99937713, -0.33048865,
        -0.5061277 , -0.14908014,  0.9785268 , -0.99043804,  0.9828222 ,
        -0.9187875 , -0.9773213 ,  0.9800687 ,  0.955108  , -0.63989365,
        -0.78066677,  0.25093687, -0.52095413,  0.35847044, -0.9796438 ,
         0.77040577,  0.5041405 , -0.11713739,  0.90462315, -0.90723217,
        -0.5658021 ,  0.3393464 , -0.57253885, -0.03464808,  0.7852318 ,
         0.5863543 , -0.2903683 ,  0.10524008, -0.3157491 , -0.3283432 ,
        -0.98630184,  0.25248316,  1.        , -0.2932054 ,  0.43194744,
        -0.39159498, -0.02471775, -0.12938915,  0.5425912 ,  0.63316727,
        -0.31224072, -0.90678704,  0.6802484 , -0.98032105, -0.98643327,
         0.88515776,  0.2762025 , -0.25967157,  0.9999937 ,  0.52587867,
         0.18437354,  0.34015328,  0.97531146, -0.00961124,  0.6977997 ,
         0.7714908 ,  0.97960067, -0.19878545,  0.5547651 ,  0.91813415,
        -0.76973844, -0.29839078, -0.6457684 ,  0.11847758, -0.93472254,
         0.04859285, -0.9728577 ,  0.9758918 ,  0.79083323,  0.37397337,
         0.29322428,  0.3463571 ,  1.        , -0.28344712,  0.74565566,
        -0.65729904,  0.89706427, -0.9992633 , -0.85835195, -0.42205122,
         0.02660483, -0.6537962 , -0.31771183,  0.3093419 , -0.97574544,
         0.5961652 ,  0.48927927, -0.99429876, -0.99184316, -0.10422545,
         0.85884523,  0.00486639, -0.9560245 , -0.71263295, -0.59398985,
         0.5138035 , -0.27638632, -0.96817255,  0.17129657, -0.295536  ,
         0.56728745, -0.26840574,  0.5732834 ,  0.6681473 ,  0.7473094 ,
        -0.42653623, -0.05367717, -0.02169049, -0.8601829 ,  0.8354379 ,
        -0.84583515, -0.73801994, -0.1758596 ,  1.        , -0.5074421 ,
         0.74395454,  0.8140395 ,  0.8012395 , -0.19783951,  0.12990536,
         0.8705507 ,  0.23519993, -0.60337013, -0.6908616 , -0.85193384,
        -0.41151592,  0.6187978 ,  0.25217745,  0.43870094,  0.85306245,
         0.75531286,  0.20293558, -0.01406304, -0.10706785,  0.9998205 ,
        -0.14611307, -0.24235162, -0.6237957 ,  0.02892364, -0.4086271 ,
        -0.5665821 ,  1.        ,  0.342323  ,  0.328192  , -0.99026304,
        -0.63736963, -0.9433317 ,  0.9999989 ,  0.9019552 , -0.87858593,
         0.6951615 ,  0.5400228 , -0.09183987,  0.8488278 , -0.18790367,
        -0.31657013,  0.317574  ,  0.13583037,  0.96701694, -0.622579  ,
        -0.97985405, -0.6803688 ,  0.42359763, -0.9725251 ,  0.9994953 ,
        -0.542078  , -0.24575908, -0.4273482 , -0.01201347,  0.7613651 ,
         0.00731448, -0.98946   , -0.11817224,  0.2206094 ,  0.97735566,
         0.1929144 , -0.591835  , -0.9492599 ,  0.50090253,  0.62826014,
        -0.76978254, -0.9621842 ,  0.9751784 , -0.9908679 ,  0.66289395,
         1.        ,  0.31703115, -0.43707806,  0.15467693, -0.56510115,
         0.36916867, -0.28950256,  0.7145889 , -0.9760138 , -0.48779896,
        -0.13801542,  0.38100198, -0.13986678,  0.13865034,  0.784588  ,
         0.20181029, -0.49005198, -0.6200816 , -0.02545768,  0.51952076,
         0.8692346 , -0.36663455, -0.19382007, -0.01067433, -0.19743322,
        -0.95507383, -0.24380404, -0.29982236, -0.9999688 ,  0.79986584,
        -1.        ,  0.2695148 , -0.08518916, -0.18281214,  0.8777597 ,
         0.5447604 ,  0.49969584, -0.8048793 , -0.694106  ,  0.61722565,
         0.81101197, -0.29681554, -0.13316315, -0.7884097 ,  0.25134793,
        -0.07460118,  0.40256706, -0.33344275,  0.8121781 , -0.24125008,
         1.        ,  0.19404748, -0.61283517, -0.9879942 ,  0.22347625,
        -0.18747559,  0.99999994, -0.9469065 , -0.9642234 ,  0.35057634,
        -0.70234084, -0.88181317,  0.2818043 , -0.00923758, -0.8131019 ,
        -0.90696543,  0.97128403,  0.9361259 , -0.61874884,  0.5001946 ,
        -0.3375339 , -0.616567  ,  0.01690421,  0.60233366,  0.99087167,
         0.48337436,  0.9235803 , -0.08378224, -0.24273983,  0.9741196 ,
         0.13318112,  0.6367294 ,  0.20994084,  1.        ,  0.2779764 ,
        -0.94073814,  0.23566417, -0.9866463 , -0.20943974, -0.97578436,
         0.27121937,  0.18821484,  0.9488337 , -0.3315034 ,  0.96209157,
        -0.5729339 ,  0.05573122, -0.5332821 , -0.03750358,  0.37780896,
        -0.9583214 , -0.9877656 , -0.9878868 ,  0.6314601 , -0.4537851 ,
        -0.0323552 ,  0.24128953,  0.11342575,  0.46291897,  0.5541575 ,
        -1.        ,  0.95559114,  0.42294934,  0.77785254,  0.9710445 ,
         0.7026142 ,  0.42804685,  0.33771977, -0.9899562 , -0.9919649 ,
        -0.40367672, -0.2135195 ,  0.7956065 ,  0.6891527 ,  0.9223903 ,
         0.4893354 , -0.51037455, -0.35977358, -0.28881362, -0.7840159 ,
        -0.99540436,  0.47370532, -0.3997906 , -0.98349714,  0.95919394,
        -0.13264774, -0.16179705,  0.13471113, -0.69341195,  0.97857916,
         0.8883015 ,  0.5587162 ,  0.13504937,  0.5614963 ,  0.9285318 ,
         0.97044104,  0.9836765 , -0.6593045 ,  0.8397449 , -0.38409153,
         0.56074977,  0.6409418 , -0.9576191 ,  0.15008189,  0.32664824,
        -0.24418157,  0.22771904, -0.26481634, -0.9884511 ,  0.34720448,
        -0.17766179,  0.64612764, -0.38605484, -0.0186708 , -0.48134714,
        -0.10996526, -0.7571417 , -0.76564854,  0.6945152 ,  0.3526681 ,
         0.9315834 ,  0.71839595, -0.12440112, -0.6379952 , -0.2399207 ,
        -0.5485674 , -0.94808227,  0.9552906 , -0.03638262, -0.05993683,
         0.3750182 , -0.04180279,  0.7299626 , -0.08958837, -0.39086553,
        -0.39726564, -0.7406826 ,  0.90645045, -0.09038296, -0.56262934,
        -0.7078029 ,  0.75853217,  0.25826415,  0.99992806, -0.564312  ,
        -0.8097277 , -0.23506235, -0.442809  ,  0.354424  , -0.39383766,
        -1.        ,  0.37609363, -0.36428654,  0.53091085, -0.62894225,
         0.57903147, -0.50878316, -0.9908445 , -0.19053973,  0.4337847 ,
         0.610516  , -0.59371257, -0.66226494,  0.5636608 ,  0.06387527,
         0.95153147,  0.8910796 ,  0.10300018,  0.35302562,  0.6912232 ,
        -0.4406702 , -0.6655127 ,  0.951942  ]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763012/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-array-how-do-i-specify-the-index-colum

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that each array must be 1 dimensional:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(y)) #this seems faster
```

or

```
#import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(map(np.ndarray.flatten, y))
#pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: x.flatten(), y))
```

---

```
#        0         1         2         3         4         5         6    \
#0 -0.945975 -0.478051 -0.650509  0.773478  0.552691 -0.190079  0.922323   
#1 -0.945975 -0.478051 -0.650509  0.773478  0.552691 -0.190079  0.922323   
#
#       7        8        9    ...       758       759       760      761  \
#0  0.27941 -0.73227 -0.99999  ...  0.563661  0.063875  0.951531  0.89108   
#1  0.27941 -0.73227 -0.99999  ...  0.563661  0.063875  0.951531  0.89108   
#
#     762       763       764      765       766       767  
#0  0.103  0.353026  0.691223 -0.44067 -0.665513  0.951942  
#1  0.103  0.353026  0.691223 -0.44067 -0.665513  0.951942  
#
#[2 rows x 768 columns]
```

**EDIT:**

It seems also good approach:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.squeeze(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame([np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([2,3,4])])
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.