# Generate a simulated dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to generate pandas dataframes with simulated data.

There should be x sets of columns.
Each set corresponds to y number of columns.
Each set should have a value, a, in z number of rows. The value, a, is a float.
However, z may be different for the different sets of column sets.
The remaining columns will have another value, b, which is also a float.

I would like to write a function to generate such pandas data frames where I can specify the variables x, y, a, b and where a specific value for z can be set for the individual column sets.

Here is an example df:

```
data = [[0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['set1_col1', 'set1_col2', 'set2_col1', 'set2_col2', 'set3_col1', 'set3_col2'])
df
```

[image]

But I would like to be able to specify the variables, which for the above example would be:

```
x = 3  #(set1, set2, set3)  
y = 2 #(col1, col2 for each set)  
a = 0.5  
z = 1 #(for all column sets)
b = 0.1
```

Advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I would love to help, but I cannot fully understand the description of the data you want. Perhaps either 1. A formal definition would help. Or 2. A small example table.

Comment: Also, perhaps what you are looking for can be easily done with numpy (e.g np.ones([size]) * a ) and then loading into pandas. Like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308247/4386933

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it! I updated the question with an example. Let me know if it is more clear now or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
N = 5 #No of rows
x = 3  #(set1, set2, set3)  
y = 2 #(col1, col2 for each set)  
a = 0.5  
z = 1 #(for all column sets)
b = 0.1 

#names of sets
sets = [f'set{w+1}' for w in range(x)]
#names of columns
cols = [f'col{w+1}' for w in range(y)]
#MultiIndex by product
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sets, cols])
#DataFrame with default value
df = pd.DataFrame(b, index=range(N), columns=mux)

#random assign a by random index with no repeat
for c, i in zip(df.columns.levels[0], np.random.choice(df.index, z * x, replace=False)):
    df.loc[i, c] = a

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df)
   set1_col1  set1_col2  set2_col1  set2_col2  set3_col1  set3_col2
0        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1
1        0.1        0.1        0.5        0.5        0.1        0.1
2        0.5        0.5        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1
3        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1
4        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.5        0.5
```

EDIT: For consecutive random values use:

```
N = 6 #No of rows
x = 3  #(set1, set2, set3)  
y = 2 #(col1, col2 for each set)  
a = 0.5  
z = 2 #(for all column sets)
b = 0.1 

#names of sets
sets = [f'set{w+1}' for w in range(x)]
#names of columns
cols = [f'col{w+1}' for w in range(y)]
#MultiIndex by product
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sets, cols])
#DataFrame with default value, index is create by consecutive groups
df = pd.DataFrame(b, index=np.arange(N) // z, columns=mux)
print (df)


#random assign a by random index with no repeat
for c, i in zip(df.columns.levels[0], 
                np.random.choice(np.unique(df.index), x, replace=False)):
    df.loc[i, c] = a

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
```

---

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   set1_col1  set1_col2  set2_col1  set2_col2  set3_col1  set3_col2
0        0.5        0.5        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1
1        0.5        0.5        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1
2        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.5        0.5
3        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.1        0.5        0.5
4        0.1        0.1        0.5        0.5        0.1        0.1
5        0.1        0.1        0.5        0.5        0.1        0.1
```

Comment: This randomly assigns the value for a to any of the sets. Therefore, two sets can be assigned the value for a in the same row. Would it be possible to only assign the value a to one column set per row?

Comment: @peter_parker - annswer was edited.

Comment: Thank you! Although, if N=6 and z=2, each set should have two rows each with the value 0.5 but this is not the case with the above code..

Comment: @peter_parker - Not understand.

Comment: How could I change the code so that the columns of each set has two rows with the value 0.5?

Comment: @peter_parker - `z=2` not working?

Comment: It does now! Thank you jezrael!